# Native messaging host launched with elevated privileges'

Tags: google-chrome-extension, elevated-privileges, chrome-native-messaging

I have developed a chrome extension which communicates with a Native Messaging Host.
About 2 month ago - suddenly - when calling chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName) the Native messaging host is launched with elevated permissions (you can see it in the task manager by adding the elevated column), as if someone run it "as administrator".

This causes a problem since I have another dotnet application that sends and receives messages to the chrome extension using this Native Messaging Host as a pipe  - it does not run with elevated privileges and thus fails to connect to the Native Messaging Host.

It worked well 2 month ago - the Host did not get launched with elevated mode.... nothing changed...

Some additional facts:

1. My chrome does not run as admin.
2. If I install the same extension in Edge - the host is launched without elevated permissions....

### Things I have tried:

1. The host was registered under Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts
   And I tryed moving it to
   Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts
   It did not help.

Does anyone have a clue why this sudden change?
what decides if a native messaging host launches as admin????

Comment: If this is a work/managed computer it could be a policy setting https://admx.help/?Category=Chrome&Policy=Google.Policies.Chrome::NativeMessagingUserLevelHosts

Comment: Hi @Strelok, thanks for responding. Indeed its a work computer.
I have admin rights so I have changed that registry value (which was set to 1) to be zero - same result.
Anyhow - I have read the policy description over and over again and it seems that it does the opposite - if the flag is set to 0 - it  will not allow the host to be launched if it is referenced from the "HKCU" - I have tried it - indeed it blocked the host from launching.
But if it is set to 1 - the host is launched.... but always with admin privilege...

Comment: There's nothing in the API that controls this behavior, so it must be a bug in Chrome. The workaround may be to write a separate utility that will act as a native host and will run the real host as non-elevated.

Comment: @wOxxOm 
My product solution folows this guide to have a chrome extention communicate with a native messaging host:

Comment: The native messaging host should not launch with admin privilege. Looks something else is happening on your machine. There's no change in Chromium source to do so: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/extensions/api/messaging/native_process_launcher_win.cc

Comment: Ended up to be a CycberArk configuration

Comment: Just been severely bitten by an elevation problem for my native messaging host today, and have CyberArk on the Work PC... What is the CyberArk configuration you're talking about?